# Unable to transfer entire balance? what is the minimun amount needed for transfer?

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, cpp-ethereum, wallet-transfer

Trying to transfer from myEtherwallet and it says "insufficient funds" - I lowered the amount and it worked, but I can't get the rest out. I've been searching for several hours (I told you I'm a rookie) and I still have .477 or so Ether in there, but it says insufficient when I know the transaction (gas?) shouldn't be too much? It defaults to 21000 and I've tried to adjust that, but I get the same message every time now for several hours.

I put in "Send entire balance" which still is a bit less than full amount (which I'm assuming is to cover transaction fee ), I hit "Send Transaction and then "yes, I'm sure" and every time, a box pops up saying "Insufficient Balance for Transfer"??

At that point, it appears I can adjust the gas limit and/or the gas price, but the only options after doing so are "Reset, Buy, or Reject" - none of which seem to be "Save" or "Update" w/ regard to if I adapt one or both of those numbers.

I don't even know if I understand what I just typed, but I would greatly appreciate any insight - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't adjust the 21000 gas.  You should ONLY adjust the gas price.

This does a better job of explaining.

https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/gas/what-is-gas-ethereum.html

P.S. if you want to PRACTICE sending ether, switch to the ROPSTEN network (upper right) and you can send/receive worthless ROPSTEN ether.

Comment: Thanks so much for being willing to respond. I've read through the notes on the link you attached, but continue to get the same message. Again, if I adjusted the gas price, the only options once I would do so are "reset (which goes back to default numbers), buy (I don't think it's a matter of not having enough since I did a "practice" one earlier of .01ETH and it went through), or reject (which I've had to keep hitting since there are no other options. Ugh - thank you again.

Comment: Sometimes myetherwallet has issues.  Close tab and re-open fresh.

Comment: Open up etherscan.io and put in your public address.  Take a look at the transactions?  Are they failing?  Does your balance look right?  Where are you transferring to?  Is is a contract or just some regular wallet?

Comment: Last one and then I'll quit bugging you - this is the comment I get that appears as I'm inputting withdrawal amount:

Comment: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex number with leading zero digits into Go struct field CallArgs.value of type *hexutil.Big

Comment: And then after rejecting, it says this: "Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature. at Object.InvalidResponse (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:14300:28007)..."

Answer (score 0):

Well - I don't know if I can tell you what I did differently this time over the prior 200 times but I just got it to go through...I'm sure it was user error - I just wish I could be useful to some other rookie in the future, but ends well so I'm thankful!

Answer (score 0):

You need about .01 ether in the same account as the token to pay for the transaction fee.

**source**: [*reddit*: Problem getting funds out of MEW](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacken/comments/7q7xxd/problem_getting_funds_out_of_mew/dsntnjq)